# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova deployment issue

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

I am using visual studio 2015 preview to develop the cordova application. I am getting the following warning and error when I try to deploy to the device.

[image]

How it can be sorted?

Comment: Which platform are you trying to to deploy to?

Comment: Android. Specially when I add the jpeg images into the images folder it happens.

Comment: That error message is not very descriptive - i suggest you turn on the diagnostic mode when you are building the project. You might be able to see something there.  To turn on build diagnostic mode  go to

   Tools > Options ... > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run > select diagnostic